# Using Backbone-Deep Model inside a collection?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, model

I've been using [Backbone-Deep-Model](https://github.com/powmedia/backbone-deep-model) because some of our data sets coming from the server have nested data (not grotesquely so).

It has been working fine individually, however when used inside a Collection, it seems that the .get() method is replaced with the original. Therefore we lose the `Deep-Model` path syntax for nested properties.

Is there a special way in which this must be handled? Any advice will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: So you're doing `collection.get('someId').get('nested.property')` and it's not working?

Comment: @idbehold Actually I'm iterating on the collection.

`Collection.each( function ( i ) { i.get('first.second'); } );`

Answer (score 0):

This works for me in some similar case:

```
$.each(collection.models, function () { this.get('first.second'); } );
```